# A function that (also) changes a replacement rule

Tags: function-construction

I'd like to write a function operating on a list, returning a list, but also changing a replacement rule. Let's say I have a list of replacement rules:

```
data={
...
a->3,
...
};
```

Now I write a function:

```
f1[{b_,c_}]:={b+1,c+1};
```

What I would also like this function to do is to change the replacement rule of `data` list, so that after the function is evaluated (with any list as an input), the variable `a` would take the value of the evaluated `c+1` expression, or `f1[[2]]` if You will. Seems like an easy task, but somehow confuses me.

**Edit:**

As an input I would like a list `l={2,3}`, and `{3,4}` as an output, and a replacement rule `a->3` changed into `a->f1[[2]]`.

In general, my problem is that I want another function later on to access a value produced by `f1`, but I would like that other function to call this value from external list and not explicitly from `f1`.

Comment: Not very clear what you want to achieve... something along `{1, 2, a -> 3} /. (a -> _) :> b -> 3`?

Comment: I would like `f1` to work on list other than `data`, let's say `l={2,3}` and to change replacement rule specified in `data` as well, if that is what You're asking. In other words, as an output i would like to get `{3,4}` and whenever I call `a` after the evaluation, I'd like to get 4.

Comment: Please give an explicit example of I/O in the question.

Comment: Still unclear to me, since data is a replacement list that does not affect the value of `a`. But If you want to change the rule for `a` in the replacement list Yves suggestion can be adapted to do what you need: first compute `f1`, then change the rule list with `data /. Rule[a,_]:>Rule[a,f1[[2]]]` and finally use `a /. data` to get the value. If you want to assign a value to `a`, why use the replacement list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me expand the comment.
If the list of replacement rules `data` is to be considered a global variable, you can access it from within your function and alter its value in this way

```
data = {a->3, ab->2, ac->1, ad->0};

f1[{b_,c_}]:=Block[{tmp},
    tmp = {b+1, c+1};
    data = data /. Rule[a,_]:>Rule[a,tmp[[2]]]
]
```

This will produce a new value for the list of rules `data` where the rule associated with `a` is changed.

```
f1[{2,3}]
```

> {a -> 4, ab -> 2, ac -> 1, ad -> 0}

If you do not wish to see the list of rules, just put a semicolon at the end of the last line of code. You can even have `f1` to return the list `{b+1,c+1}` in this way:

```
f1[{b_,c_}]:=Block[{tmp},
    tmp = {b+1, c+1};
    data = data /. Rule[a,_]:>Rule[a,tmp[[2]]];
    tmp
]
```

Once you have evaluated `f1`,

```
f1[{2,3}]
```

> {3, 4}

to get the value of `a`, you will use

```
a /. data
```

> 4

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. I almost figured it out myself, that answer came just in time. Peltio , @Yves Klett I'll make sure to give You some credit in my thesis!

Comment: If I would like to change also replacement rule for `ab` in `data` list, I can make `data = data /. Rule[a,_]:>Rule[a,tmp[[2]]]; data = data /. Rule[ab,_]:>Rule[ab,tmp[[1]]];` inside `Block[]`, is there a shorter way to do that, just in case I want to change more rules?

Comment: You can use `data = data /. {Rule[a, _] :> 
    Rule[a, tmp[[2]]], Rule[ab, _] :> Rule[ab, tmp[[1]]]}`. Of course if you have dozens of such replacements, we could create a more elaborate replacement rule or better yet, a function that accepts the names of the variables whose rules should be changed and the position in the list of the associated new values.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Simply this?

```
f1[{b_, c_}] := Module[{a, d},
  data = {a -> 8, d -> 7};
  {a, d} = {b + 1, c + 1};
  {a, d} /. data]
 f1[{2, 3}]
```

> (8, 7}

Further to OP's comment ...

```
data = {a -> 8, d -> 7};
f1[{b_, c_}] := Module[{},
  {a, d} = {b + 1, c + 1};
  {a, d} /. data]
f1[{2, 3}]
```

> (8, 7}

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what i was looking for. The replacement rule to be changed has to be defined outside of the function.